# How do you install a specific package version with Spago?

Tags: purescript, spago

With tools like `npm` we can install a specific version

```
npm install foo@1.2.0
```

How do you install a specific version using `spago install`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, that's not what `spago install` does. Instead of "adding a package to your project", `spago install` downloads all packages that are currently referenced in your `spago.dhall` file.

Secondly, the idea with Spago is that you don't choose a specific package version. Instead what you choose is a "snapshot", which is a collection of certain versions of all available packages that are guaranteed to compile and work together. This is a measure intended to prevent version conflicts and versioning hell (and this is similar to how [Haskell `stack`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) works)

The snapshot is defined in your `packages.dhall` file, and then you specify the specific packages that you want to use in `spago.dhall`. The version for each package comes from the snapshot.

But if you *really* need to install a very specific version of a package, and you *really* know what you're doing, then you can modify the snapshot itself, which is described in `packages.dhall`.

By default your `packages.dhall` file might look something like this:

```
let upstream =
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/purescript/package-sets/psc-0.13.5-20200103/src/packages.dhall sha256:0a6051982fb4eedb72fbe5ca4282259719b7b9b525a4dda60367f98079132f30

let additions = {=}

let overrides = {=}

in  upstream // additions // overrides
```

This is the default template that you get after running `spago new`.

In order to override the version for a specific package, add it to the `overrides` map like this:

```
let overrides =
  { foo =
      upstream.foo // { version = "v1.2.0" }
  }
```

And then run `spago install`. Spago should pull in version `1.2.0` of the `foo` package for you.